# JsonReaderExcecption was unhandled

Tags: c#, parsing, response, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize a response I get from using RestSharp. I have IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

From that response, I'm trying to convert the response.Content into a Json object, of which I made classes for, but, it seems like there's an error and I can't quite pinpoint where or why.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYPin.png)

Comment: Is the json data well formatted? Looks like a parsing issue. Is the class RootObjectt correct?

Comment: Is your API returning JSON data or XML?? The content seems to be having an issue- it does not seem to be a JSON data